# How to allow duplicate keys in map in java?

Tags: java, string, linkedhashmap

```
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Map<String,Double> map=new LinkedHashMap<String,Double>();
        line=br.readLine();        
        while(!line.equals("End")) {
            String[]arr2=line.split(" ");
            String model=arr2[1];
            Double distance=Double.parseDouble(arr2[2]);
            map.put(model, distance);
            line=br.readLine();
        }
```

Im trying to print all the keys and values although they are duplicate.

**My input should be**

**Audi 15.3**

**Audi 8.6**

**BMW 45**

**End**

 And when im trying to print it, it gives me only (Audi 8.6 and Bmw 45).

I need to print twice audi!

Comment: Keys in a map are unique. However you can associate a list of doubles to a key.

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have duplicate keys in a map. The best you can do is have something like a list in the values. i.e. `Map<String, List<Double>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Double>>();`

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is using object-oriented programming.

### Create new class

```
class Result {
    String model;
    String distance;

    public Result(String model, String distance) {
        this.model = model;
        this.distance = distance;
    }
}
```

### Change type of

from

```
Map<String,Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,Double>();
```

to:

```
List<Result> list = new ArrayList<Result>();
```

### Change adding method

from:

```
map.put(model, distance);
```

to:

```
list.add(Result(model, distance));
```

Answer (score 0):

You Map declaration looks like `Map<String, Double>` that means, that only one `Double` value can be mapped to `String` key.

You can simply, change `Double` to `List<Double>` and map a key to the list, then your case look like:

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Map<String, List<Double>> map=new LinkedHashMap<>();
line=br.readLine(); 
while(!line.equals("End")) {
    String[] arr2=line.split(" ");
    String model=arr2[1];
    Double distance=Double.parseDouble(arr2[2]);
    List<Double> distances = map.computeIfAbsent(model, key -> new ArrayList<>());
    distances.add(distance);
    line=br.readLine();
}
```

This structure more correct, meaning the model `Audi` has a list of different distances. Key one `Audi` and list of values.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have duplicate keys in a straight-forward Java map. One approach you can use it to hold a `List` of values instead of a single value, and iterate over them when you're printing out the results:

```
BufferedReader be = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Map<String, List<Double>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
line=br.readLine();        
while(!line.equals("End")) {
    String[] arr2 = line.split(" ");
    String model = arr2[1];
    Double distance = Double.parseDouble(arr2[2]);
    map.computeIfAbsent(model, m -> new LinkedList<>()).add(distance);
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

And then, when you print it out:

```java
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Double>> entry : map) {
    for (Double d : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not my favourite thing to do, but there is a workaround to allow duplicates in a Map. The LinkedHashMap you are using, uses the hashCode method defined in Object.
You could create a wrapper class around String, without overriding the default implementation of equals and hashCode. This would allow you to add "duplicates" to your collection, because Java thinks they are not identical.

Example class:

```
public class StringWrapper {
   private String value;

   public StringWrapper(String value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

// getters and setters
// no equals and hashcode
}
```

Comment: If you do that, it means you didn't need a map in the first place.

Comment: @Olivier if you need duplicates in your collection, a map is not what you need. But still, my answer is an answer to the question. No need to downvote.